# Use break keyword in the method body

Tags: ruby

I have two loops here:

```
loop do
  prompt(messages('APR_amt', LANGUAGE))
  APR_amt = Kernel.gets.chomp

  if valid_number?(APR_amt)
    break
  else
    prompt(messages('not_valid_num', LANGUAGE))
  end
end

loan_duration = ''
loop do
  prompt(messages('loan_duration', LANGUAGE))
  loan_duration = Kernel.gets().chomp()

  if valid_number?(loan_duration)
    break
  else
    prompt(messages('not_valid_num', LANGUAGE))
  end
end
```

This part keeps on repeating for every loop:

```
if valid_number?(loan_duration)
  break
else
  prompt(messages('not_valid_num', LANGUAGE))
end
```

Just different variable passing by on it. 
Now what I did is that I created a method for it to shortened my codes:

```
def check_number(varname)
  if valid_number?(varname)
    break
  else
    prompt(messages('not_valid_num', LANGUAGE))
  end
end
```

But this one did not work. Instead I got an error that pertains to break.
How can I create a method that will work on all of my variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can `raise StopIteration` instead of calling `break`. But note that they are not equivalent:

- `raise StopIteration` jumps of a loop created with the `loop` statement. The exception is not handled by loops created with statements such as `while`, `for`, or methods such as `each`. It has a dynamic scope, which means that it goes up the call stack until it finds the loop (which can be defined in a completely different place in the code).
- `break` jumps out of any block. It has a lexical scope, which means that the block must enclose the `break` statement in the code. In your code there is no block around `break` (a method is not a block), and that's the reason you got an error.